# Cannot show the png representation of a score using MusicScore

Tags: python, music21

Using music21 in order to display a png of the score [following instructions](https://web.mit.edu/music21/doc/usersGuide/usersGuide_08_installingMusicXML.html):

> Some formats have sub-formats, for instance both musicxml and lilypond have a .png subformat which
> converts directly to a .png file. To use that, call .show("musicxml.png").

```
import music21 as m21    
us = m21.environment.UserSettings()
us['musicxmlPath'] = r'C:\Program Files\MuseScore 3\bin\MuseScore3.exe'
us['musescoreDirectPNGPath'] = r'C:\Program Files\MuseScore 3\bin\MuseScore3.exe'


s = m21.corpus.parse('josquin/milleRegrets')
s.show('musicxml.png')
```

> File "C:\Users\xxx\miniconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
> hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Le fichier spécifié est introuvable

Same error in Jupyter and Spyder. Of course the path to MuseScore is correct. Replacing `musicxml.png` by `musicxml` works, MuseScore opens and display the score.

Comment: What version of music21? This sounds like something we patched in 6.7.0.

Comment: @JacobWalls: I used version 6.5.0. After updating to 6.7.1 the problem was gone. Thanks. You're doing a great job with this library.